# Object Oriented design - dealing with items and inventory

Tags: java, oop

I work on my first java project, which is a basic roleplaying game. I have a question in regard to dealing with items and inventory. First, I'd overview some classes. Item is an abstract class that describes all items. Item's subclasses are Weapon (abstract class) and Armor (very plausible that I'll have a few more in the future). Weapon has two subclasses - MelleWeapon and RangedWeapon. That's sums up how items are dealt class-wise. In addition, I have an Inventory class, that describes the inventory of each character.

The code works, but needs some upgrade. I have at least two major problems:

First, each concrete subclass of Item has a getItem method, which is almost identical. How can I avoid this code duplicity ?

Second, addToInventory method in Inventory can get longer as I add more subclasses to Item (lots of if/elseif), so I guess it's a bad design. How can I avoid using if in an elegant way?

```
abstract public class Item {

private String name;
private long cost;
private double weight;

public Item(String name, double weight, long cost) {
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.cost = cost;
}

public String getName() { return name; }
public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

public double getWeight() { return weight; }
public void setWeight(double weight) { this.weight = weight; }

public long getCost() { return cost; }
public void setCost(long cost) { this.cost = cost; }

}


abstract public class Weapon extends Item{

private boolean oneHanded;
private String reqTraining;
private int n;
private int dice;
private int attackBonus;
private int damageBonus;


Weapon(String name, double weight, long cost, boolean oneHanded, String reqTraining,  int n, int dice, int attackBonus, int damageBonus) {
    super(name, weight, cost);
    this.oneHanded = oneHanded;
    this.reqTraining = reqTraining;
    this.n = n;
    this.dice = dice;
    this.attackBonus = attackBonus;
    this.damageBonus = damageBonus;
}


String getReqTraining(){ return reqTraining; }
int getN() { return n; }
int getDice() { return dice; }
int getAttackBonus() {return attackBonus; }
int getDamageBonus(){ return damageBonus; }

public abstract void attack(Character attacker, Character defender);
}



public class Armor extends Item{

private String reqTraining;
private int acBonus;

Armor(String name, String reqTraining, int acBonus,double weight, long cost) {
    super(name, weight, cost);
    this.reqTraining = reqTraining;
    this.acBonus = acBonus;
}

static List<Armor> armorList = new ArrayList<Armor>();

static
{
    armorList.add(new Armor("Full Plate Armor","Heavy", 8, 25, 200));
    armorList.add(new Armor("Chain Mail Armor","Medium", 5, 18, 120));

}

String getReqTraining(){ return reqTraining; }
int getACBonus() { return acBonus; }


public static Armor getItem(String itemName) {
    try {
        for (Iterator<Armor> iter = armorList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            Armor item = iter.next();
            if (itemName.equals(item.getName())) {
                return item;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(itemName + " haven't been found in spells-list");
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}

}




public class  MeleeWeapon extends Weapon {

boolean throwable;

MeleeWeapon(String name,boolean oneHaned, String reqTraining, int n, int dice, int attackBonus, int damageBonus,double weight, long cost, boolean throwable) {
    super(name, weight, cost, oneHaned, reqTraining, n, dice, attackBonus, damageBonus);
    this.throwable = throwable;
}

static List<MeleeWeapon> meleeWeaponList = new ArrayList<MeleeWeapon>();

static
{
    meleeWeaponList.add(new MeleeWeapon("Long Sword",true, "Martial", 1, 8, 0, 0,8, 10, false));
    meleeWeaponList.add(new MeleeWeapon("Short Sword",true, "Martial", 1, 6, 0, 0,5, 5, false));
    meleeWeaponList.add(new MeleeWeapon("Dagger",true, "Basic", 1, 4, 0, 0,2, 3, true));
    meleeWeaponList.add(new MeleeWeapon("Quarter-staff",false, "Basic", 1, 4, 0, 0,3, 2, false));
    meleeWeaponList.add(new MeleeWeapon("Shield",false, "Martial", 1, 4, 0, 0,8, 8, false));

}


public void attack(Character attacker, Character defender){

    int attackRoll = DiceRoller.roll(20) + attacker.getBaseAttackBonus() + attacker.getModifier(attacker.getStrength()) + getAttackBonus() ;
    System.out.println(attacker.getName() + " attack Roll: " + attackRoll + "AC: " + defender.getArmorClass());

    if (attackRoll >= defender.getArmorClass()){
        System.out.println("Defender: " + defender.getName() + " had " + defender.getCurrentHp());
        int damage = DiceRoller.roll(getN(), getDice()) + attacker.getModifier(attacker.getStrength()) + getDamageBonus() ;
        System.out.println("Damage : " + damage);
        defender.setCurrentHp(attacker.getCurrentHp() - damage);
        System.out.println("Defender: " + defender.getName() + " has " + defender.getCurrentHp());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Missed Attack");
    }

}

public static  MeleeWeapon getItem(String itemName) {
    try {
        for (Iterator<MeleeWeapon> iter = meleeWeaponList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            MeleeWeapon item = iter.next();
            if (itemName.equals(item.getName())) {
                return item;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(itemName + " haven't been found");
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}


}




public class RangedWeapon extends Weapon {

private String shoots;

RangedWeapon(String name, boolean oneHaned, String reqTraining, String shoots, int n, int dice, int attackBonus, int damageBonus, double weight, long cost) {
    super(name, weight, cost, oneHaned, reqTraining, n, dice, attackBonus, damageBonus);
    this.shoots = shoots;
}


static List<RangedWeapon> rangedWeaponList = new ArrayList<RangedWeapon>();

static {
    rangedWeaponList.add(new RangedWeapon("Long Bow", false, "Archery", "Arrow", 1, 8, 0, 0, 5, 10));
    rangedWeaponList.add(new RangedWeapon("Short Bow", false, "Archery", "Arrow", 1, 6, 0, 0, 3, 5));
}


public void attack(Character attacker, Character defender) {

    int attackRoll = DiceRoller.roll(20) + attacker.getBaseAttackBonus() + attacker.getModifier(attacker.getDexterity()) + getAttackBonus();
    System.out.println(attacker.getName() + " attack Roll: " + attackRoll + "AC: " + defender.getArmorClass());

    if (attackRoll >= defender.getArmorClass()) {
        System.out.println("Defender: " + defender.getName() + " had " + defender.getCurrentHp());
        int damage = DiceRoller.roll(getN(), getDice()) + attacker.getModifier(attacker.getStrength());
        System.out.println("Damage : " + damage);
        defender.setCurrentHp(attacker.getCurrentHp() - damage);
        System.out.println("Defender: " + defender.getName() + " has " + defender.getCurrentHp());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Missed Attack");
    }

}

public static RangedWeapon getItem(String itemName) {
    try {
        for (Iterator<RangedWeapon> iter = rangedWeaponList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            RangedWeapon item = iter.next();
            if (itemName.equals(item.getName())) {
                return item;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(itemName + " haven't been found");
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}

}



public class Inventory {

private Map<String,Item> inventory;

Inventory() {

    inventory = new HashMap<String, Item>();
}


public void showInventory() {

    System.out.println("Show Inventory: ");

    for (Map.Entry<String,Item> entry: inventory.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        }

    System.out.println(" ");
}


public void addToInventory(String itemName) {

    Item newItem = null;

    try {

        if (MeleeWeapon.getItem(itemName) != null) {
            newItem = MeleeWeapon.getItem(itemName);
        } else if (RangedWeapon.getItem(itemName) != null) {
            newItem = RangedWeapon.getItem(itemName);
        } else if (Armor.getItem(itemName) != null) {
            newItem = Armor.getItem(itemName);
        }else
            System.out.println("Add futural other options (like potions) ");

            System.out.println(newItem.getName() + " has been added to inventory");
            inventory.put(newItem.getName(), newItem);

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Adding " + itemName +"to inventory has failed");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: While this might still be in scope for stackoverflow, I'd like to tell you about https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you have similar questions in the future - might be slightly more fitting.

Comment: Good to know that there's another option in case the scope of my question is broader.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you are using Strings to identify objects in your program, which is a common anti-pattern and a big source of bugs and performance problems.

If you identify things with plain strings you have the problem that (a) there could be a typo in the name when you use it and (b) you have to look the things up all of the time.

You should use Java identifiers to identify things. The usual way is to use a `public static final`. For example:

```
public static final Armor FULL_PLATE_ARMOR = new Armor("Full Plate Armor","Heavy", 8, 25, 200)
```

You can then just use this identifier in your code and you can add it to arrays if you want a pick-list in your GUI.

You can then delete your `getItem` method.

Comment: As for now, no GUI is planned, so how can I deal with it ? . Plus, I can't use a Map by using the suggested public static final.

Comment: You mean it is text based? I am not sure what you mean by your question. I think you need to write more code (the user interaction bit) and then it will be clearer. You will see you don't need the strings. You are probably going to have a menu of some kind.

Comment: Yeah, just a basic IO menu, nothing fancy

Comment: So easier for the player if you show a list of options and they enter a number and you use that to get the item from an array. Iif you do want the user to enter the item names (maybe search for an item) I would add all items to one big list and then check the type afterwards with `instanceof`.

Comment: I thought about using a big list, but I'm not sure that creating itemList is an elegant way to deal with the problem, it can lead to a code duplicity.Plus, I'm not sure that using lots  instanceof is the best design in this case.

Comment: My advice: create the public static finals. Then continue with your code and see what kind of lists you actually need.

Comment: Now my code use objects rather than strings, that was a good advice!

Comment: Great - glad it worked out. The code probably looks a lot better, and if you are using an IDE, you can use auto-complete to enter the names.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly solutions, but two tips:

- Your getItem() is not efficient. Think about using a Set structure to store the data, then the access is O(1). In any case, you do not need iterators if you use the "new" kind of for loop.
- Think about using generics, which might reduce your "double implementations".

Comment: A `Map` may be more appropriate than a `Set`